# How to approach this?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T: V −→ W be a linear transformation. Assume that (v1, v2, . . . , vn) is a linearly independent set of vectors in V. Is it true that (T(v1), . . . , T(vn)) is also linearly independent in W. (Justify your answer)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Can you show us your effort and indicate where exactly you are struck so that we may better help you

Comment: What about $T(v)=0$ for all $v\in V$ ?

Comment: We don't know if T(v)=0  for all v∈V  (It is not given)

Comment: Think again about that last comment of yours.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not in general, if $\text{dim}(W)<n$ the result is false for any $T$. If $\text{dim}(W)\geq n$ It might be true, but depends on the $T$. For example if $T$ is injective the result is true, but this is not a sufficient condition.

Comment: Should T be both surjective and injective if not Then what are the necessary conditions?

Comment: You are not saying that $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$, so you cant find anything better I think.